# Make Bootstrap 3.0 NavBar content always collapsed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, toggle, navbar

I need to make a section of a NavBar of Bootstrap 3.0 always collapsed.

Actual sections of the navbar:

- Links
- Search Form
- Login Form

When I open the website in a phone I see the three sections collapsed and I have three icons to collapse each of this content.

When I open the page in a PC i see the three sections in the bar visibles (not the buttons to collapse). What I need? In PC view only hide the Login form and show the button to collapse that login form. No matter the resolution i need to have the login button always visible and the section collapsed. This is my actual code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <!--Toggles -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle boton" 
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sesion">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle boton"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#links" id="menuToggle">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle boton" 
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#buscar">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
        <!--Logo en vista Mobile -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding: 10px 0 0 15px" href="#">
            <span class="visible-xs">
                <img src="img/nsnow.png" width="37" height="36" alt="Logo" />
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="collapse navbar-collapse nav navbar-nav" id="links">
        <!--Links -->
        <li><a style="padding-left: 40px"></a></li>
        <li class="botonMenu" id="boton_generos"><a >Géneros</a></li>
        <li class="botonMenu" id="boton_categorias"><a >Categorías</a></li>
        <li class="botonMenu" id="boton_senales"><a >Señales</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="buscar">
        <!--Buscar -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn boton">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="sesion">
        <!--Buscar -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn boton">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
         </form>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076922/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to override some css to make it stay collapsed

http://jsbin.com/UpeZazi/1/edit

In this example i made the "user login" button stay collapsed.

css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #login-btn {
    display: block;
  }

  #sesion.collapse {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

html:

basically the same except i added the id `login-btn` to your login user button element:

```
<button type="button" id="login-btn" class="navbar-toggle boton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sesion">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
 </button>
```

Answer (score 9):

For those using LESS, head to `variables.less` and change:

```
@grid-float-breakpoint:     @screen-sm-min;
```

to:

```
@grid-float-breakpoint:     999999999px;
```

One line change that works like a charm. Just be sure to use an unrealistically large number of **pixels** (em did not work for me).

Comment: rather than to sabotage the sourcecode, you could just create a new less file, import the bootstrap main-less file, and declare the above mentioned variable again. When it compiles it uses your overwritten value in bootstraps sourcecode. Thats the beauty of less.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @cfx answer, overriding variable grid-float-breakpoint (which I prefer) using SASS:

```
$grid-float-breakpoint:     999999999px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Case you can't change the less variables, you can also override the bootstrap classes after 768px(smartphone bounder). Bellow is the working code that overrides basic navbars with **dropdown menus**. Not all classes are overriden bellow, so depending on what you are using, you may need to override other classes.

```
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
            position: static;
            float: none;
            width: auto;
            margin-top: 0;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
            line-height: 20px;
        }
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
            padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
        }
        .dropdown-menu > li > a {
            display: block;
            padding: 3px 20px;
            clear: both;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            color: #333;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .navbar-header {
            float: none;
        }
        .navbar-toggle {
            display: block;
        }
        .navbar-collapse {
            border-top: 1px solid transparent;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }
        .navbar-collapse.collapse {
            display: none!important;
        }
        .navbar-nav {
            float: none!important;
            /*margin: 7.5px -15px;*/
            margin: 7.5px 50px 7.5px -15px
        }
        .navbar-nav>li {
            float: none;
        }
        .navbar-nav>li>a {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .navbar-text {
            float: none;
            margin: 15px 0;
        }
        /* since 3.1.0 */
        .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
            display: block!important;
        }
        .collapsing {
            overflow: hidden!important;
        }
    }
```

[click here for the live demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/punx96L5/)