# How to make Navbar collapse from 1024 pixel screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I know there are so many solution for this but they didnt worked for me . I dont know what the problem is :

What i want is my navigation menu collapse from screen size 1024px 
I also checked :

[Bootstrap: How to collapse navbar earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076922/bootstrap-how-to-collapse-navbar-earlier)

```css
.navbar-nav li:hover{
  background: #f1b703 !important;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a{
  color: #fff !important;
}



.icon_ref{
  padding: 15px 5px !important;
}


.icon_ref i {
  font-size: 18px;
}



.navbar-nav li a{
  padding-left: 10px !important;
  padding-right: 10px !important;
  font-family:'Lato';
  color: black !important;
  line-height: 56px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
{
  .navbar-left {
    position: relative;
    left: 9%;
  }

  .logo{
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    bottom:12%;
}

}

@media (max-width: 1125px) and (min-width: 1024px){

  .navbar-nav li a{
    padding-left: 6px !important;
    padding-right: 7px !important;    
  }

 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Buy Sell Rent Everyting">
<!--                 <img style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;"
                     src="//www.google.com/favicon.ico">
 -->
                     <img style=" margin-top: -7px;"
                     src="http://madisonmountaineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/MM_header_logo.png">
                
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" >
            <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/about/">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/#expeditions">EXPEDITIONS</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/gallery/">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/#press">PRESS</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/garrettmadison/">GARRETT MADISON</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/dispatches/" style="color: red !important;">DISPATCHES</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MadisonMtng" class="icon_ref"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color: #3b5998;"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/madisonmtng" class="icon_ref"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="color: #00aced;"></i></a></li>
           
            <li><a href="https://youtube.com/madisonmtng" class="icon_ref"><i class="fa fa-youtube" style="color: #bb0000;"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://instagram.com/madisonmtng" class="icon_ref"><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="color: #5e3e23;"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/madisonmtng" class="icon_ref"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" style="color: #dd4b39;"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is cs and i have written css i tried code from other similar question in stackoverflow similar question .

I dont know if media query position is wrong or what thet didnt worked .

Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following css code and give the value as you wish. This will give the breakpoint to the collapsed menu.

Updated. 
I added an extra class to each place `.navigatsioon` . Then it worked

```css
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .navigatsioon ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  .navigatsioon .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navigatsioon .navbar-left,
  .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navigatsioon .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigatsioon .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navigatsioon .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navigatsioon .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navigatsioon .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navigatsioon .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navigatsioon .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navigatsioon .collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    transform: translatex(-45%);
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navigatsioon">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header navigatsioon">
      <button button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navigatsioon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-center navigatsioon" rel="home" href="#" title="Buy Sell Rent Everyting" >
        <!--<img style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;"
        src="//www.google.com/favicon.ico">
     -->
        <img style=" margin-top: -7px;" src="http://madisonmountaineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/MM_header_logo.png">

      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navigatsioon navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navigatsioon navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/about/">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/#expeditions">EXPEDITIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/gallery/">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/#press">PRESS</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/garrettmadison/">GARRETT MADISON</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/#contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://madisonmountaineering.com/dispatches/" style="color: red !important;">DISPATCHES</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MadisonMtng" class="icon_ref"><i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color: #3b5998;"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/madisonmtng" class="icon_ref"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="color: #00aced;"></i></a></li>

        <li><a href="https://youtube.com/madisonmtng" class="icon_ref"><i class="fa fa-youtube" style="color: #bb0000;"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://instagram.com/madisonmtng" class="icon_ref"><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="color: #5e3e23;"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/madisonmtng" class="icon_ref"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" style="color: #dd4b39;"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you need the expanded version of nav bar?

Comment: No i just have fine navbar it collapse in 768px now but i want it to collapse from 1024px .. i am using bootstrap 3 . does there is any thing on the placement position of css and bootstrap file ???

Comment: Check this example. But unfortunately its not working with the version 3.3.7 https://www.bootply.com/120604 . I think no.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I had to add an extra class to get it work. But it will just get the job done. Not a good approach I think. But no other option for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164521/discussion-between-pravin-poudel-and-lakindu-gunasekara).