# Mobile menu always open

Tags: css, mobile, menu

Keep mobile menu always open

Hello community:

I need to keep the mobile menu open at all times, without the need to click on the three horizontal bars icon. Mobile menu appears at 768px and below.

I tried the code below, based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597897/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-achieve-an-always-collapsed-navbar-dropdown-menu).

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
.btn-navbar-header
{
    float: none;
}

.btn-navbar-toggle
{
    display: block;
}

.btn-navbar-collapse.collapse
{
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

However, it didn´t work.

Please advice. Here is the link to the [Website](https://www.redecx.com)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
<div style="height: auto;" id="header-responsive-inner" class="responsive-links nav-collapse in collapse">
```

so become

```
<div style="height: auto;" id="header-responsive-inner">
```

exactly i just remove this:

```
class="responsive-links nav-collapse in collapse"
```

you can edit your javascript that related to code above.

reference : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y5Kh.png)

Comment: To @dhanyn10 your idea is great; I used "collapse in" instead of "responsive-links nav-collapse collapse" and I managed to have the menu opened all times; but I had to hide the navigator icon as it quit the toggle function. Still looking for a better solution. Thanks