# Bootstrap collapse menu for all resolutions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use Bootstrap, but I want to make the collapsed menu to be used across all resolutions. How might I go about doing this? Would it be through the customize page and in the media queries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Bootstrap 3.0 NavBar content always collapsed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896591/make-bootstrap-3-0-navbar-content-always-collapsed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a link to a navbar with a menu-hamburger icon that toggles the menu, as shown here:

```css
.glyphicon-menu-hamburger {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div>
    <a href="#" 
       data-toggle="dropdown">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">chocolate</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">strawberry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">lemon</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Click here to see result: http://codepen.io/Kebten/pen/EjXJqO